# Jboss EAP7.3, Migration RestEasy 3.0.x to 4.x, jaxrs-api

Tags: migration, resteasy, jboss-eap-7

Jboss EAP7.3, Migration RestEasy 3.0.x to 4.x, jaxrs-api

I found
https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/pull/1697/files

https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/4.0.0.Final/userguide/html/Migration_from_older_versions.html#Migration_to_RESTEasy_3.1

1. Should with Jboss EAP 7.x only used RestEasy3, or can also be used RestEasy4 ?
2. How to migrate following ?

   ```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>
   ```

Comment: I would suggest using 3.x with JBoss EAP 7.x. It is the only supported version currently. There is a plan to migrate WildFly to 4.x and eventually JBoss EAP will follow. On JBoss EAP 7.3 however you should be using RESTEasy 3.11.x. What is it from 4.x that you want to use?

Comment: We did a contrast-security-scan: CVE-2020-25633 (CVSS 5)
A flaw was found in RESTEasy client in all versions of RESTEasy up to 4.5.6.Final. It may allow client users to obtain the server's potentially sensitive information when the server got WebApplicationException from the RESTEasy client call. The highest threat from this vulnerability is to data confidentiality. Contrast recomends to upgrade version 3.x to > v4.5.6.Final

Comment: This was fixed in JBoss EAP 7.3.5.GA https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2021:0248. It sounds like that suggestion is not quite right.

Comment: ok, we manually configured 3.0.x with Jboss EAP 6.x, then we migrated to EAP 7.3.x but not to >= 7.3.5GA